# How to create a reorder button outside the client panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, reorder

How can I create a Reorder button outside the client panel (`/customer/account/`)?

I tried to copy and paste the code on my `home page` but got the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStore() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Reorder.php on line 57
```

The code that I copied is this one:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
<span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
<?php endif ?>
```

This page is only loaded if the user is logged in.

Thanks :)

Comment: you have to create instance of $_order

Comment: I added a `<?php $_orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>` at the beginning of the page but it didn't worked

Comment: but for which order you want to show reorder link? for all orders?

Comment: only for the last one

Comment: $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->setOrder('increment_id', 'DESC')->setPageSize(1)->getFirstItem();

Comment: The page turned into a security error page D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place below code in your template file

```
<?php
if (Mage::app()->isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    $_customer=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $_customer->getId())
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->setPageSize(1);
    if($orders)
    {?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/order/reorder', array('order_id' => $orders->getFirstItem()->getId())) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
    <?php }
    }
} ?>
```